# How to access a specific node in XSL

Tags: xslt

silly question but hoping I can get some help here, I need to access specific node in XSL, the XML I am provided with looks like the below, can someone give me an idea what my XSL should look like in order to access the content of the node 'Value' I cannot no matter how i try reach that node!- any help appreciated!!!! :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
<Group Level="1">
    <Group Level="2">
        <Details Level="3">
            <Section SectionNumber="1">
                <Field Name="Field5" FieldName="{ARTransaction.Transactions}">
                    <FormattedValue>0.00</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>0.00</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field15" FieldName="{ARTransaction.PostingDate}">
                    <FormattedValue>8/1/2016</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>2016-08-01</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field14" FieldName="{ARTransaction.AuditTrail}">
                    <FormattedValue>2016083100154</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>2016083100154</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field13" FieldName="{ARTransaction.JobN}">
                    <FormattedValue>-25043</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>-25043</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field11" FieldName="{Customer.CustomerName}">
                    <FormattedValue>First Church of Christ</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>First Church of Christ</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field7" FieldName="{ARTransaction.CustomerN}">
                    <FormattedValue>13157</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>13157</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Field6" FieldName="{ARTransaction.InvoiceN}">
                    <FormattedValue>25043</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>25043</Value>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="SalesmanN1" FieldName="{ARTransaction.SalesmanN}">
                    <FormattedValue>22</FormattedValue>
                    <Value>22</Value>
                </Field>
            </Section>
        </Details>
    </Group>
    </Group>
</Group>
<ReportFooter> </ReportFooter>
```

XSL :

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:element name="CrystalReport">   
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="version">1.2</xsl:attribute>     
    </xsl:element> 
    <xsl:element name="DR">
    <xsl:value-of select="Group/Group/Details/Section/Field[@Name='Field13']/Value"/>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please provide a complete XML as well as the expected result (see:[mcve]). There are several `Value` elements in your input, so your request is not clear.

Comment: Sorry - not terribly clear was I!
The following XML is the complete one, I am trying to access the node of 'Value' where Field Name='Field13', I have no idea how to reach this with XSL....

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I have added my attempt at XSL to the above XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your attempt is that it ignores the *default namespace* of the source XML.

You need to declare the namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix, and use that prefix when addressing the elements in the source XML. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSL 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns1:CrystalReport">
    <DR>
        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:Group/ns1:Group/ns1:Details/ns1:Section/ns1:Field[@Name='Field13']/ns1:Value"/>
    </DR>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
  <Group Level="1">
    <Group Level="2">
      <Details Level="3">
        <Section SectionNumber="1">
          <Field Name="Field5" FieldName="{ARTransaction.Transactions}">
            <FormattedValue>0.00</FormattedValue>
            <Value>0.00</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="Field15" FieldName="{ARTransaction.PostingDate}">
            <FormattedValue>8/1/2016</FormattedValue>
            <Value>2016-08-01</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="Field14" FieldName="{ARTransaction.AuditTrail}">
            <FormattedValue>2016083100154</FormattedValue>
            <Value>2016083100154</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="Field13" FieldName="{ARTransaction.JobN}">
            <FormattedValue>-25043</FormattedValue>
            <Value>-25043</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="Field11" FieldName="{Customer.CustomerName}">
            <FormattedValue>First Church of Christ</FormattedValue>
            <Value>First Church of Christ</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="Field7" FieldName="{ARTransaction.CustomerN}">
            <FormattedValue>13157</FormattedValue>
            <Value>13157</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="Field6" FieldName="{ARTransaction.InvoiceN}">
            <FormattedValue>25043</FormattedValue>
            <Value>25043</Value>
          </Field>
          <Field Name="SalesmanN1" FieldName="{ARTransaction.SalesmanN}">
            <FormattedValue>22</FormattedValue>
            <Value>22</Value>
          </Field>
        </Section>
      </Details>
    </Group>
  </Group>
</CrystalReport>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DR>-25043</DR>
```

---

**Note**: If you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor, you can declare a `xpath-default-namespace` attribute and do away with the prefix.